# UDF scala return [max,index]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I want to implement the following function to Spark SQL. Given an array return the maximum value with the index. I've tried:

```
/*
 * This function finds the maximum value and corresponding index in the array. NULLs are ignored. 
 * Return type is array in format [max, index], and its element type is the same as the input type.
 * Parameters: x Array[Int]
 * Returns: Array as [max, index].
 */
def array_max_index(x: WrappedArray[Int]): WrappedArray[Int] = {
    val arr = collection.mutable.WrappedArray.empty
    arr.:+(x.max).:+(x.indexOf(x.max))
}
```

This works well, **but only for `Integers`** - I want the UDF to work for other numeric values (e.g. `Double`s). I've tried the following, but I can not return a structure with types:

```
def array_max_index[T](item:Traversable[T])(implicit n:Numeric[T]): Traversable[T] = {
    val arr = collection.mutable.WrappedArray.empty
    val max = item.max
    val index = n.toInt(item.toSeq.indexOf(max))
    arr.:+(max).:+(index)
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you try it? Does it not work? It should work...

Comment: Yes, this code works , but only for integer arrays . I want it to work well with Double types.

Comment: Then state that in the question... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning an `Array` is not that useful - since the index type is always `Int`, and the max value type depends on the specific call (if I understand correctly, you want it to work well for Integers and Doubles) - so the array can't be typed properly.

Here's one possible implementation of the UDF, returning a **tuple**:

```
def array_max_index[T](x: Traversable[T])(implicit n: Numeric[T]): (T, Int) = {
  (x.max, x.toSeq.indexOf(x.max))
}
```

Then, can be called for `Double`s as well as for `Int`s:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("array_max_index", array_max_index(_: Traversable[Double]))

sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT array_max_index(array(
    |  CAST(5.0 AS DOUBLE),
    |  CAST(7.0 AS DOUBLE),
    |  CAST(3.0 AS DOUBLE)
    |)) as max_and_index""".stripMargin).show
```

Which prints:

```
+-------------+
|max_and_index|
+-------------+
|      [7.0,1]|
+-------------+
```